# Nginx Is giving me error when I type service nginx start

Tags: nginx

Today I was installing nginx with pterodactyl.io but It Is giving me errors and nginx can't start. Can you help me please?

```
    root@Myserver:~# systemctl status nginx.service
 nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabl   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-06-24 20:12:33 UTC; 17s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 23704 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --p  Process: 23550 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=e  Process: 23707 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on Main PID: 23553 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 24 20:12:33 Myserver systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a rJun 24 20:12:33 Myserver systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a Jun 24 20:12:33 Myserver nginx[23707]: nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencryJun 24 20:12:33 Myserver nginx[23707]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.Jun 24 20:12:33 Myserver systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=eJun 24 20:12:33 Myserver systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'Jun 24 20:12:33 Myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web serverlines 1-16/16 (END)
```

Thanks

Comment: Would you share some piece of nginx's error log to narrow down the question?

Comment: Use `nginx -t` to test the Nginx configuration.